# Are there Browser and Client Certificate/Key interactions besides mTLS handshake?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, certificate, microsoft-edge

I know that if presented with an mTLS request an modern browser will request the user select a certificate from a store (OS-based or in Firefox's case NSS-based). I was wondering if there is any other way for the Webpage that is returned after the mTLS handshake to requests actions be performed with the users certificate or private key, such as:

- Can the webpage be aware of the selected certificate and read some of the field with a Javascript API? (IE: `<h1> Hello {x509CommonName}</h1>`)
- Can the webpage request that the user sign something with their private key? (little risky but potentially useful)

I am *not* asking how easy it is to just use the web server to reflect the certificate back to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the client side, it is not possible to obtain the certificate used in the SSL connection, nor to perform a digital signature. The browser keystore is not accessible via JavaScript. Although there has been some attempt to develop a standard API, it seems that it is not succeeding. See https://www.w3.org/TR/webcrypto-key-discovery/

On the server side you can easily obtain the certificate used. Any web server will provide it to the application layer. The web page could navigate to a zone with ssl two ways authentication, the server would retrieve the certificate and return it in the response